# Web2py URL callback hidden when clicked and loading ajax

Tags: ajax, url, web2py

I have been developing an application using web2py. I have a page with a callback link which sends information to another function, this loads the results via ajax in the right sidebar of the page. When the link is clicked, the link itself disappears but the results are loaded correctly. I have to refresh the page for the links to come back. I have been looking at this for ages but can't figure it out, I am relatively new to web2py so probably missed something obvious. 
Here is some code:

The view (With the link):

```
{{if hosts == "Please select a category":}}
{{response.write("Please select a category")}}
{{else:}}
    <ol>
        {{for i in hosts:}}
            <li>{{=A(i['HostName'], callback=URL('selection','getResults.load', vars=dict(clicked=i['HostName'])), target="monitoredDevice")}}</li>
        {{pass}}
    </ol>
{{pass}}
{{end}}
{{block right_sidebar}}
<div id="monitoredDevice">

</div>
{{end}}
```

The controller action:

```
def getResults():
hostName = request.vars.clicked
# hostName = request.vars.hostNameSelected
print(hostName)
try:
    task_status = scheduler.task_status(db.scheduler_task.task_name==hostName, output=True)
    result = task_status.result
    # create_compare_graph()
except(AttributeError): # Error is because there is no scheduler and therefore no status, need to set the values to 0
    result = emptyTaskStatusResultsToZero()
try:
    return dict(result)
except(TypeError): # There is a task scheduled however there is no run data as it has not been run before. Causes an error.
    return emptyTaskStatusResultsToZero()
```

I think there is something wrong with the =A link in the view?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide more detail on `emptyTaskStatusResultsToZero`?

Answer (score 0):

The method just prevents the view from getting an error if nothing is returned so I set all the values to zero so the view has something to render.

```
def emptyTaskStatusResultsToZero():
return {'percent_diff_in': 0, 'percent_diff_out':0, 'now_avg_30mins_in': 0
    , 'now_avg_30mins_out':0, 'prev_week_avg_30mins_in':0, 'prev_week_avg_30mins_out':0,
              'percent_more':0,'percent_less':0, 'count':0}
```